# How to filter articles by category to find out the exact number of pages for pagination (JS)

Tags: javascript, filter, pagination, gatsby

In my Gatsby JS websites, I have categorized articles and I managed to create a page for each category and to paginate each page based on a maximum number of articles to be shown on a page. 
The issue is that instead of calculating the exact number of existing pages per category, my code calculates the total amount of existing pages (based on all articles, and not on articles by category).

This is the code:

gatsby-node.js

```
let categories = []
 _.each(result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges, edge => {
     if (_.get(edge, "node.frontmatter.categories")) {
        categories = categories.concat(edge.node.frontmatter.categories)
        }
    })

    const categoryarticles = categories.filter(category =>{
        return category === category
    })

    const categoryarticlesPerPage = 6
    const numPages = Math.ceil(categoryarticles.length / categoryarticlesPerPage)

    //Creating a PAGINATED page for each category, so that any category page will only display a certain amount of articles (defined in categoryarticlesPerPage)
    Array.from({ length: numPages }).forEach((el, i) => {
        categories.forEach(category => {
            createPage({
                path: i === 0 ? `/${_.kebabCase(category)}` : `/${_.kebabCase(category)}/${i + 1}`,
                component: categoryTemplate,
                context: {
                    category,
                    limit: categoryarticlesPerPage,
                    skip: i * categoryarticlesPerPage,
                    numPages,
                   currentPage: i + 1,
                },
          })
      })
 })
```

The mistake is undoubtedly in the const categoryarticles.

The desired result would be to calculate the number of articles by category, so that the category pagination starts working properly (right now, it creates more pages than necessary as it considers the entire amount of articles present on the website).

Any clue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
const categoryarticles = categories.filter(category =>{
  return category === category
})
```

always returns the whole array since `category === category` is always `true`. One of those `category` variables should be different. You probably need to filter on `articles`.

Also, this seems like a perfect job for `_.flatMap`, like so:

```
const categories = _.flatMap(result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges, edge => {
  return _.get(edge, "node.frontmatter.categories", []);
});

// get articles from somewhere
const categoryarticles = articles.filter(category => {
  return article.category === category;
});
```

If you want to count the number of articles in each category, you can use the `_.countBy` as follows:

```
const categoryWiseArticleCount = _.countBy(articles, article => {
  // return the article category here
  return article.category;
});

console.log(categoryWiseArticleCount);
// {
//   category_1: 7,
//   category_2: 10,
// }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help! So I've tried the following:  

const articles = result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges

const categoryarticles = articles.filter(category =>{
            return article.categories === category
        })

and it says that article isn't defined. 

(Please note that in the return article.categories, categories in plural form is not a mistake, that's the attribute in the markdown files). 

What am I missing?

Comment: The `article` variable - it's not defined here. Where do you get it from? I've not used `Gatsby` before and therefore do not exactly know how to get the `article`.

Comment: I only know how to define articles, but I have no idea on how to define a single article. Is there any other way to achieve the result?

Comment: If I do like so: `const categoryarticles = result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.filter(edge => edge.node.frontmatter.categories === 'management')`  it kind of works. It takes all the articles of the category 'management' and the pagination starts working according to that number. How can I manage to use the category variable instead of hardcoded one, so it adjusts for each category of the categories array?

Comment: I updated the answer to do that. Please take a look.

Comment: Okay, let's start a chat please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186230/discussion-between-giulia-and-faizuddin-mohammed).